# Volatility Error - The requested file doesn't exist

Tags: volatility

I am running the program [Volatility](http://code.google.com/p/volatility/downloads/list) on a Kali Linux machine. However, whenever I try the command

`vol -f <memdump name> <plugin name>`

I get the error

`ERROR: volatility.plugins.fileparam: The requested file doesn't exist`

I tried downloading the source code and running Volatility as a python script, and I've tried changing  and  for the command above, but the error persists.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing the memdump name with the absolute path of the memdump name seems to do the trick. This is clearly a bug with the program.

Bug Report!

Answer (score 0):

This is Bug. O.K. No solution at all, that's also O.K.
Replacing file name with full path, doesn't appear to work.

Comment: This is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error occurred when having the file in another drive, and even when using the absolute path, it did not work, but when I moved the file to the /home/user folder, the program worked correctly.